# my jQuery code works with vs 1.8.3 and lower

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery. you can see all my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/WjGMM/4/
it works fine in 1.8.3 an older, but I'd like it to work in 1.10.1. I need it to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var counter = 2;

$("#add").live("click", function() {
  var newZip = $(document.createElement('div'))
   .attr("id", "zip" + counter);

  newZip.html('<div class="control-group" id="zip' + counter + '"><div class="controls"><input type="text" id="zip' + counter + '" name="zip' + counter + '" class="span2" placeholder="zip code" maxlength="5"><input type="text" id="fed' + counter + '" name="fed' + counter + '" class="span2" placeholder="# fed"></div></div>');
  newZip.appendTo("#zipcodes");

  counter++;
  });

});
```

I'm curious if this is a bug, or maybe I'm using something that's outdated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The outdated thing you're using is [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live).

Comment: Have you considered reading the [jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)?

Comment: @Barmar I'm very new. Didn't know about it. but thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.live` is deprecated; change the code to use `$.on` instead.